# How to use checkbox to store row values after button click in handsontable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, handsontable, rhandsontable

I want to store the values of the cells that are present in the row corresponding to the checkbox which is present at the end of the row in the form of an array. This should happen when the user selects a checkbox and clicks a button at the end.

Kindly help

```js
var container = document.getElementById('inputTable'); 
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data, //here data is an array of objects with keys mentioned in the columns section below
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    columns:[{data:'well_id'},{data:'layer_id'},{data:'date'},{data:'oil'},{data:'water'},{data:'gas'},{type:'checkbox'}],
    editor:false
});
```

Comment: Hello Utkarsh So in abstract you want that when a user click on a checkbox the value indicated in the row be stored in an array that it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Kindly share the jsfiddle or the code.

Comment: the fact is that you can make that when a user click on a checkbox it write some value in a variable via a callback.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition would be that when a user click on a checkbox it write some value in a variable via a callback.

In pseudocode form :

```
// Declare var array in global scope
var array = []
// specify the action which launch the callback
If user click on the checkbox, then launch [callbackFunction(value)] 

// define the callback function
callbackFunction (value) { 
// then fill the array with the value of the checkbox
var array.push(value);
}
```